# How to test EME with PlayReady?

Tags: html5-video, html5-audio, drm, playready, mse

Google provides a reference application for EME with PlayReady. See EME with PlayReady: http://goo.gl/0vdok

Which browser/operating system combination supports this reference setup? According to the documentation from Microsoft Internet Explorer 11 should support EME/PR on Win 8.1 or Win 10, but in my tests the Internet Explorer does not recognize the video format.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft published this video player reference with PlayReady encyrpted content plays back in IE11 and Edge on Win8.1/10. You can also input your stream to test: http://aka.ms/azuremediaplayer?url=%2F%2Famssamples.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net%2F91492735-c523-432b-ba01-faba6c2206a2%2FAzureMediaServicesPromo.ism%2Fmanifest.  You could also see Widevine encrypted content playback in Chrome using the same player.

Azure Media Player is a JavaScript player that detects the browser capability and choose appropriate streaming protocols and DRM technology accordingly. It is free to use with Azure Media Services.

Cheers,
Mingfei Yan

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in stating that IE11 on Win8.1+ supports the PlayReady Content Decryption Module (CDM) with EME. I am not sure about the player at the link you provided (http://goo.gl/0vdok), but one good way to test this fact is to use a player which correctly uses whatever CDM is in the current browser, such as this one: http://www.dash-player.com/demo/drm-test-area/.

This player will use the WideVine CDM on Chrome, and the PlayReady CDM on IE11+ on Win8.1+.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you please also share the values you entered in the player at LA URL & MPD? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I just left the default values that are pre-entered there -- they worked out of the box for me.

Comment: Ah... ok. But does the reference player from dash-player.com also support the video from http://goo.gl/0vdok in your tests? I will also test it, but right now I just read that EME/PR is not support on Win8.1 or Win10 if you run it in a virtual machine. (I used Paralells on OSX). Now I am on the way to setup a PC properly and run the test again.

Comment: I suspect if you run in a VM, you'd run smack into secure content path protection Microsoft implements throughout the Windows driver stack. See [Protected Media Path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376846(v=vs.85).aspx)  for more details.

Comment: hm... I setup Win 10 with IE 11 on a PC and tried to run the example http://www.dash-player.com/demo/drm-test-area/, but the video playback does not start. On the bottom of the page is also a chart available that shows the current bitrate. The strange thing is that I see there that the player seems to get video data, but actually the video is not visible. Really strange. @Guido Domenici: Which OS/browser combination do you use and did you install any PlayReady runtime extension?

Comment: Sorry no idea @HH. ... it used to work for me last time I tried but indeed does not now. I am on Win8.1 with IE11.